# Usage of "I would prefer"

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences

I've been studying the different structures between 'prefer' and 'rather'. I have a few questions.

1. Can use 'to' after 'would prefer' like

> I'd prefer you **to** stay at home tonight.

2. Can I use the past tense after 'would prefer' like 'would rather'?
   If I can, are the meanings of these two sentences the same?

> I'd **rather** you didn't go out. vs I'd **prefer** you didn't go out.

3. Should I put 'that' after 'would prefer'?

Comment: "prefer it if..." is better.

Comment: @Mick Why don't you write an answer?

Comment: @Rathony I could not easily provide any supporting evidence. As is often the case, I know "what", but I don't know "why".

Comment: @Mick We can use would prefer + object pronoun + to-infinitive or would prefer it if + past simple. "Prefer it if" is just more polite and i guess more formal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.grammarbank.com/would-rather-would-prefer.html

- I'd prefer you to stay at home tonight. = I'd rather you stayed at home tonight.
- I'd prefer (it if you didn't) you not to stay at home tonight.  = I'd rather you didn't stay at home tonight.
- I'd rather you didn't go out. vs I'd prefer you didn't go out. - Possible, yet better to say: **I'd prefer you not to go out.** or **I'd prefer it if you didn't go out.**

Yes, you can use or not use "that".

- "I'd prefer that you don't go out"